# Format input using thousand separator as user type in a React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently working on a React App using Typescript but I am currently having  a little issue.

I have a simple input field that is meant to receive an amount as input from users and format it in thousands as follows

```
                <input
                    value={amount}
                    className={classes.searchBox}
                    onChange={(event) => setFormattedAmount(event.target.value)}
                />
```

Now I have a function to handle the change of the input field as below so that the formatting happens as the user is typing

```
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("100,000");

  const setFormattedAmount = (value: any) => {
        let amountString = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(parseFloat(value));
        setAmount(amountString);
    }
```

However, it isn't working as I expected. I am getting an **NaN** during the formatting as the user types.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `new Intl.NumberFormat().format(parseFloat(value)));` this is +1 parens!
I can imagine it is receiving a `falsy` value as the argument. e.g.: `false` | `null` `''` you should check it before you run formatting like: `if(!value) {...}`

Comment: @sonkatamas that was a typo. That wasn't the cause unfortunatley...I have updated the question to reflect that.Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I just wanted to leave a comment about the typo but I've also mentioned the falsy values, those yield `NaN`! +1: spin up the `debugger` and inspect the value!

Comment: @sonkatamas Ok.Thank you so much for your response. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work..Can you bring it out of the comment and be more elaborate, maybe that way I would get it working..Thanks a bunch though.

Comment: Basically I just try to point out that you should somehow figure out `value` at the time of the function invocation. You can do it with `console.log()` or with the `debugging` as well! I would suggest you `debugging` but `console.log()` does the job as well! Example:
`console.log(value); let amountString = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(parseFloat(value));`

Comment: How about changing the input type to `type="number"` for input value type-safety. Then you can use `toLocaleString` to convert the value to thousands: `parseFloat(value).toLocaleString()`

Answer (score 0):

I've played with this code a little bit and I'm pretty sure that you're getting this error because when the field is focused or of there is no text in the field it is calling the function `setFormattedAmount('')` and just by adding a simple check that the value doesn't work either.

this is what i've come up with it keeps the commas in the right place and prevents users from inputting anything that isn't a number

```
const setFormattedAmount = (value: string) => {
        if (value && !isNaN(parseFloat(value))) {
            //format the input value to have no commas
            const inputValue = value.split(',').join('');
            //reformat the string with commas in the correct positions
            const amountString = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(parseFloat(inputValue));
            setAmount(amountString);
        } else {
            setAmount('');
        }
    };
```

this will also prevent the function breaking if anyone inputs anything that isn't a number.